# Speed of the slider images should be increased in wordpress

Tags: images, homepage

Iam using  **Enlightenment**  theme of wordpress, i have added Sliders to my wordpress site by creating a new page in the admin page,

[image]

it looks like

[image]

the problem now i have is , the sliders i have added into my site is sliding very slowly,

it takes so much time for the 1st image to slide, same for the 2nd and 3rd image also

how can the speed of the sliders be increased ??

Please HELP !!

Comment: please refer the site am working on       http://mobeeload.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This is only a quick fix and not a permanent solution (i.e. a theme update might reset these changes).

The enlightment theme uses a slider called "flexslider". To alter the speed you can go into the flexslider javascript-file and change the slideshowSpeed parameter.

In your theme folder, navigate to the file "jquery.flexslider.js". 
It is located at "enlightment > core > js".
Open the file in a text editor and on line 1073 you'll find the default settings for the slideshow speed:

> slideshowSpeed: 7000, //Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds

Changing this value should allow you to set your own speed.